# Nested Typescript Generics

Tags: typescript, generics, nested-generics

I have the following classes:

```
class Walls { }
class Furniture { }
class Layout<T extends Walls | Furniture> { }
class Space extends Layout<Walls> { }
class Room extends Layout<Furniture> { }
```

I need to create these two classes:

```
class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Space> { }
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Room> {}
```

To do this, I can't create `LayoutController` class like this:

```
class LayoutController<T extends Layout>{ }
```

because `Layout` needs a Type parameter.

I can instead create this:

```
class LayoutController<U, T extends Layout<U extends Walls | Furniture>>{ }
```

but that would mean I will have to do this:

```
class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Walls, Space> { }
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Furniture, Room> {}
```

which I feel is redundant. Moreover, it opens up room for errors. There's nothing stopping me from writing:

```
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Walls, Room> {}
```

How do I solve this?

More details about `LayoutController`:

```
class LayoutController<T> extends React.Component<{}, LayoutControllerState<T>>() { }
interface LayoutControllerState<T> { 
  selectedLayout: T;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on implementation of `LayoutController`? It seems that it could be defined as `class LayoutController<T extends Walls | Furniture>` but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @AlekseyL. it is a React component that has a field called selected layout in state.
```
class LayoutController<T> extends React.Component<{}, LayoutControllerState<T>>() {
}
interface LayoutControllerState<T> {
  selectedLayout: T;
}
```

Comment: OK, so you can type inner layout filed as `Layout<T>` where `T` is generic parameter of `LayoutController`

Comment: @AlekseyL. formatting is broken in comments. Please see the edit in the question itself.

Comment: @AlekseyL.that would mean I have to write `class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Walls> { }`, not `LayoutController<Space>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a bit more typing a two type parameter solution is not bad and will give you appropriate errors if `U` is not compatible with the `T` expected by layout, if type constraints are properly specified:

```
class Walls { height!: number; }
class Furniture { price!: number; }
class Layout<T extends Walls | Furniture> { children: T[] = []; }
class Space extends Layout<Walls> { private x: undefined; }
class Room extends Layout<Furniture> { private x: undefined; }

class LayoutController<U extends Walls | Furniture, T extends Layout<U>>{
    getValue(u: U) : void{}
}

class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Walls, Space> { }
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Furniture, Room> {}
class ErrController extends LayoutController<Walls, Room> {}  //Type 'Room' does not satisfy the constraint 'Layout<Walls>
```

We can use a conditional type to extract the generic parameter from the `Layout` type and provide this as  default for `U`. Thus we don't have to specify the redundant parameter:

```
type ExtractLayoutParameter<T extends Layout<any>> = T extends Layout<infer U> ? U: never;
class LayoutController<T extends Layout<any>, U extends Walls | Furniture= ExtractLayoutParameter<T>>{
    getValue(u: U) : void{}
}

class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Space> { }
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Room> {}
new SpaceController().getValue(new Walls())
new SpaceController().getValue(new Furniture()) // error
```

We could also use the conditional type instead of `U` thus not allowing the user to change `U` to a derived type of that accepted by the layout (depeding on your use case a feature or a design limitation you decide):

```
type ExtractLayoutParameter<T extends Layout<any>> = T extends Layout<infer U> ? U: never;
class LayoutController<T extends Layout<any>>{
    getValue(u: ExtractLayoutParameter<T>) : void{}
}

class SpaceController extends LayoutController<Space> { }
class RoomController extends LayoutController<Room> {}
new SpaceController().getValue(new Walls())
new SpaceController().getValue(new Furniture()) // error
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! Didn't know there's so much in Typescript :) I'll read up more before I use conditional types, infer etc. But your two parameter solution is simple for now. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulsattarMohammed And there is plenty more in Typescript ;-).