# Model/Collection typescript typings for children

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've tried to work though various typings typings to handle a Model/Collection pattern but I'm stuck.  In short, both a Model and a Collection has a `serialize()` method on it.  Calling the serialized method on the Collection would serialize all Model(s).

Here is a [Typescript Playground that's I've been working on](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZB5AIgUQDJRMcBLAdgFwFMAnAMwEMBjQyAZRO3IBtsAvQgE1gHsPCnIAbyiR8ATwAOhAFyQAzvmJ4A5gG5wAX3A4CJCtTi9%20ASV1kqNYZHkNmbQgAoAlLPpK77Lkabqt4UBDQcEhosgDC3ARU%20BhYeETmBm6MLJ4RUZT4kIQAHkS4HHJ0tqmcPHwCVpC45AC2MvKKKr7alEzkckXp%20NGQ2LUSTIT1BEXlJmb6liISAK4ARiyU1XUNCkq4atrWc4vYy5SR67OZ3MQONfWy6ypOQiLW%20AAW2HIAdJc0ALwr9erWfh2CyWNncpWcrhK9g43V6VWsxEI%20FmxFw92sGNEkgaACJYZkcQAaB4Yz6yZ6vD6rYmYjT-SBaPwBDCQMLwVCoZBhAAqxngADlYtp4noLMUwdCIkwhplsJEADywAB86Mgh1mBFkuFmtXmJHp2CItTkskEoJS9ghcAZLR0CSmrO40sIssipntFnlxhVVXVmuqOr1xANRpNkGM6hEcih7CtyQ8nClMvwctwXqVtraHS6TuTqb6AyGI3wOedrtw7tF1EV3kriUIAG0ALo%20mbA-Zq7ga-BawP6tt7ZaG4Zh8ZMOtTZuRoGDzu4Y6nc7D42yMcTizNwmd7u93UkO7w0Qvd7Loo-U-0x7Ht5%20rI-W-0wGQXYg6MS2MucUWtK5l0phVrpMG4tqqCJIiiaKHtYt7ktet40pifShrBlKnm8tTkBIDgOMudxfCqy5vG%2036OE4TgIQCj6aNozJBNyyC0Ly-IAOJCv4wCQNyx59EUADuTwkDQxgAOS1I0JwANZvNYxiQKQhD8JALASUJ1QKRwojcJAHBaXI3D1BSmxKdgKlHpSbxvOAhzzlk1k9JkSZ-vmPy4IQvGOmW-5pvi%20BKg4IgNq57k%20Q4OIAELYNKOLkWpwWRPZ%20ChWF3DzNFTYIQATOATiRtZCjmgmMLxdEjnlpA97FQ5v7lkRMakZGxGFT5pVeW8aGkGcyBUE82F2dEeGttBRxOoQbxMNwygOAABgAqm%20wlFJ8PGQAAJIIfWZFS9QaFNTiaDlQA).

```
/**
 * MODEL
 */
interface SerializedModel {
  type: string;
}

interface ModelInterface {
  serialize(): SerializedModel;
}

/**
 * MODEL: Contact
 */
interface SerializedContact extends SerializedModel {
  name: string;
}

class Contact implements ModelInterface {
  public name: string;

  public constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public serialize(): SerializedContact {
    return {
      type: "Contact",
      name: this.name,
    };
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * COLLECTION
 */

interface SerializedCollection<M> {
  count: number;
  items: { serialize(): M };
}

interface CollectionInterface<I> {
  count: number;
  items: I;

  serialize(): SerializedCollection<I>;
}

class Collection implements CollectionInterface<ModelInterface[]> {
  public count: number;
  public items: ModelInterface[];

  public constructor(items: ModelInterface[], count: number) {
    this.items = items;
    this.count = count;
  }

  public serialize(): SerializedCollection<ModelInterface[]> {
    return {
      count: this.count,
      items: this.items.map((item) => item.serialize()),
    };
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * TESTING
 */

// This is where I'm stuck.  I feel like I need to do something like this...
const contactCollection = new Collection<Contact>(
  [new Contact("Bill"), new Contact("Bob")],
  2
);

const serializedContactCollection = contactCollection.serialize();

serializedContactCollection.items.forEach((contact) => {
  console.log(`User's name is ${contact.name}`)
});
```

---

Revision: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZB5AIgUQDJRMcBLAdgFwFMAnAMwEMBjQyAZRO3IBtsAvQgE1gHsPCnIAbyiR8ATwAOhAFyQAzvmJ4A5gG5wAX3A4CJCtTi9+ASV1kqhADyxIhAB5FcHOXQbM2nHnyYA+ISLk3FnYACgBKWVh1LXBQCGg4JDRZAGFuAip8DCw8InMDeiV3dg40jMp8WwdCJxdCxmDPIwFhSEhccgBbGXlFFWjtSiZyORcy-EzIbE6JJkJughcvEzN9K3riznHMv1bICQBXACMWSkhKdIViA4ruYhDDk+wzju7ZK5UwoUgYtsfT+RBDzhWQbRqldITCr+NptYiEfAHYi4GGwtriKSyABE2wqWIANCI0a8evgABbYOQAOhJhLRGnUbS0MTiGEgKXgqFQyBSABVjPAAHLZbS5PQWVxFcFpJhzCrYdLWKqOZyGbymPJrSxgjxcZo+XYiC4HAiyXAHTpHEiMqZETpySIAbQAugMdJqJTK5fgFbgNeLqEr7Cqls1-fl1kCSstfIa2sbTe0LVbiDbsHaHXAXeoAlHCCDJQ1dV7CPLFbAfG6hiMxtxZaWfeXlTVVTHw1qddH9X5prN5jV8LX62W-asLNY4-tjgCLrgrjd8HcHtPnrb5pnYC78VOnmcE-gzcmSF9BD9tH8V2dAlLgRFC5sIcPG7gJ6i4QikSi9mj97JyZSqX3Ok0TXe0-wpal03XKlOnICQQhCKDOi+ABeHs7Spa8i1CMIwmApkbWZbRWQSXlkFoflBQAcRFUgTRHSBlARXFBwLAAFYhuE6SkrBLEd23HFiDVReFEWRSAOK4niqXhOQ6wAN3zIl2kIAB3dk629X0QmUtpHVwNSNPKfAQixAAhbBZSxPCVPUljTLM7gjms518NhAAmZSwhEbyYlnBRzkhTIXBQxjmKCio5HCHNZyhQcqXJGoQguJ9fUgNDUX8yosIfPjn3SwLUvSTC82i89ARvEo8t9KkkOpUg7mQKgyQQ2LMlQyd40uOtCCpJhuGUEIAAMAFVrwAchcEkphcAASQQ2oqGkukIDRIHIJxREkGh5sW-AEu2jQhrCQiTs0bygA)

Comment: Could you please include the code from the playground into the post? You can still include the playground link, but ideally a [mcve] does not require other users to go to another website.

Comment: Sure thing.  The post has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 3 ways to do this, depending on whether you want to keep the type information for the specific `ModelInterface` in `CollectionInterface` or not and what you want the type parameter for `CollectionInterface` to be.

First, let's fix the typings for `ModelInterface` and `SerializedCollection`, which should use [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
// A type that can serialize into a M, which must be a SerializedModel
interface ModelInterface<M extends SerializedModel> {
  serialize(): M;
}

// Contact can serialize into SerializedContact
class Contact implements ModelInterface<SerializedContact> { /* ... */ }

// A serialized collection of Ms
interface SerializedCollection<M extends SerializedModel> {
  count: number;
  // I believe this is what you want (instead of { serialize(): M })
  items: M[];
}
```

### Option 1: Separate type parameter for the `ModelInterface`

This way, you get to keep the type information of the specific `ModelInterface`s in the `CollectionInterface`. However, I was not able to get this working with type inference correctly; you'll need to explicitly state the type parameters when constructing a `Collection`.

The code for `Collection` below also uses [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties), which is just a more convenient way of doing something like `class C { public x: number; constructor(x: number) { this.x = x } }`.

```
// A type that can serialize into a collection of Ms from the serializable Is
interface CollectionInterface<M extends SerializedModel, I extends ModelInterface<M>> {
  count: number;
  items: I[];
  serialize(): SerializedCollection<M>;
}

// A class that implements CollectionInterface for a model M and model interface I
class Collection<M extends SerializedModel, I extends ModelInterface<M>> implements CollectionInterface<M, I> {
  constructor(public items: I[], public count: number) {}

  public serialize(): SerializedCollection<M> { /* ... */ }
}

// If you don't specify the type parameters TS will infer contactCollection to be
// Collection<SerializedModel, Contact> for some reason
const contactCollection = new Collection<SerializedContact, Contact>(
  [new Contact("Bill"), new Contact("Bob")],
  2
);
// type Contact[]
const contacts = contactCollection.items;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZB5AIgUQDJRMcBLAdgFwFMAnAMwEMBjQyAZRO3IBtsAvQgE1gHsPCnIAbyiR8ATwAOhAFyQAzvmJ4A5gG5wAX3A4CJCtTi9+ASV1kqhADyxIhAB5FcHOXQbM2nHnyYA+ISLk3FnYACgBKWVh1LXBQCGg4JDRZAGFuAip8DCw8InMDeiV3dg40jMp8WwdCJxdCxmDPIwFhSEhccgBbGXlFFWjtSiZyORcy-EzIbE6JJkJughcvEzN9K3riznHMv1bICQBXACMWSkhKdIViA4ruYhDDk+wzju7ZK5UwoRi2x9P5IIecKyDaNUrpCYVfxtNrEQj4A7EXDQmFtcRSWQAIm2FUxABoRKjXj18AALbByAB0xIJqI06jaWhicQwkBS8FQqGQKQAKsZ4AA5bLaXJ6CyuIpgtJMOYVbDpaxVRzOCUNDxcZq7EQXA4EWS4A6dI4kBlTIidOSRADaAF0Bjo8ms2dwZYQ5elTI6LIr7Mq6oCSssmHjIMYlTUVUHPWLqNYfFq2jq9e1DcbiKbsObLaHbeoAgHCMDVZtwa73bg4-ahiMxi7Zfh5RWbL6I-7JeqgyGwy3aoZvNH8lZYPGpjM5gt8LWyw2PatvbAuwn9sd-hdcFcbvg7g8V88zfNs8ZbSG-nuk-h9amSF9BD9l08zoF26EIsWpXW3TOm0vYfDEci9lRc9ZDJClKXPWlUX3C0QPJKlMwPSlOnICQQhCBDOi+ABePwMMpJ81RfMJIMZU0mW0FkEh5ZBaD5AUAHFhTXBRzghTJpXrRtICw9pCAAd2dadG0sUF1RxfAQ3EnwQhEK1cH451ynwEJMQAIWwGVMWI3iBPElTVO4I4tJtSCACZwDCdRmMqNdIUnbjWKUjjP0bSkMLkKzLkqAiS3E5zywc2z2I-ct8ILcI8x898nJCr83KzSlSDuZAqFJNCgoqbCl2Yl1CEpJhuGUEIAAMAFUnwAchcYkphcAASQQMvwakukIDRisszRLKAA)

---

### Option 2: `CollectionInterface`'s `items` are only known to be any `ModelInterface<M>`

This way has the benefit of not needing to specify the type parameters. However, if you need to know that `contacts` below is `Contact[]` and not just `ModelInterface<SerializedContact>[]`, you'll need to use option 1.

```
// A type that can serialize into a collection of Ms
interface CollectionInterface<M extends SerializedModel> {
  count: number;
  items: ModelInterface<M>[];
  serialize(): SerializedCollection<M>;
}

// A class that implements CollectionInterface for a model M
class Collection<M extends SerializedModel> implements CollectionInterface<M> {
  constructor(public items: ModelInterface<M>[], public count: number) {}

  public serialize(): SerializedCollection<M> { /* ... */ }
}

// type Collection<SerializedContact>
const contactCollection = new Collection(
  [new Contact("Bill"), new Contact("Bob")],
  2
);
// type ModelInterface<SerializedContact>[]
const contacts = contactCollection.items;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhZB5AIgUQDJRMcBLAdgFwFMAnAMwEMBjQyAZRO3IBtsAvQgE1gHsPCnIAbyiR8ATwAOhAFyQAzvmJ4A5gG5wAX3A4CJCtTi9+ASV1kqhADyxIhAB5FcHOXQbM2nHnyYA+ISLk3FnYACgBKWVh1LXBQCGg4JDRZAGFuAip8DCw8InMDeiV3dg40jMp8WwdCJxdCxmDPIwFhSEhccgBbGXlFFWjtSiZyORcy-EzIbE6JJkJughcvEzN9K3riznHMv1bICQBXACMWSkhKdIViA4ruYhDDk+wzju7ZK5UwoRi2x9P5IIecKyDaNUrpCYVfxtNrEQj4A7EXDQmFtcRSWQAIm2FUxABoRKjXj18AALbByAB0xIJqI06jaWhicQwkBS8FQqGQKQAKsZ4AA5bLaXJ6CyuIpgtJMOYVbDpaxVRzOCUNDxcZq7EQXA4EWS4A6dI4kBlTIidOSRADaAF0Bjo8ms2dwZYQ5elTI6LIr7Mq6oCSstfCidXr2objcRTdhzZbDN5PWLqNYfLb1AEA4RgarNuDXe7cCn7UMRmMXbL8PLCzZfTUVaD1UG-NNZvMavgy-nKx7Vt7YFrfsd-hdcFcbvg7g8h88zfM40HE-krP3bXj9tOzqH8PqIyQvoIfuunmdApKgREc1Ly27u9WBzC4QikSjUVvZGSKZSt7TUbOLe-ySpGM50pTpyAkEIQmAzovgAXmbc1KVPNVQjCMIf0ZU0mW0FkEh5ZBaD5AUAHFhRHBRzghTJpQrKtIFg9pCAAd2dLsqxCEQrVwZjnXKfAQkxAAhbAZUxdDGJYnF+KE7gjjEm0fwAJnAMJ1HIyoR0hDt6MoviaJvKtKWguQ1MuSpkNzKT9ILHTNOo68CyQzNwnTCyrz0hzbyM2NKVIO5kCoUlILsio4PvciXUISkmG4ZQQgAAwAVVPAByFxiSmFwABJBBC-BqS6QgNHi1TNFUoA)

---

### Option 3: Use the `ModelInterface` as the type parameter for `CollectionInterface`

This is similar to option 1 in that the type information of the specific `ModelInterface`s is kept, but doesn't require specifying the type parameters like option 2. However, it requires a type assertion in `Collection`'s `serialize`.

```
// This is the same ModelInterface as above, but with M defaulting
// to SerializedModel for convenience
interface ModelInterface<M extends SerializedModel = SerializedModel> { /* ... */ }

// A helper type to get the SerializedModel type from a ModelInterface
type GetModel<I extends ModelInterface> = I extends ModelInterface<infer M> ? M : never

// A type that can serialize from the model interfaces Is
interface CollectionInterface<I extends ModelInterface> {
  count: number;
  items: I[];
  serialize(): SerializedCollection<GetModel<I>>;
}

// A class that implements CollectionInterface for a model interface I
class Collection<I extends ModelInterface> implements CollectionInterface<I> {
  constructor(public items: I[], public count: number) {}

  public serialize(): SerializedCollection<GetModel<I>> {
    return {
      count: this.count,
      // Needs a type assertion here otherwise TS thinks item.serialize() is
      // just a SerializedModel
      items: this.items.map((item) => item.serialize() as GetModel<I>),
    };
  }
}

// type Collection<Contact>
const contactCollection = new Collection(
  [new Contact("Bill"), new Contact("Bob")],
  2
);
// type Contact[]
const contacts = contactCollection.items;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-m+dxRNUUIjrCCrFpOpbTt6ITzteSIomiGJYtigGyDSdL0oBzLYh+dqEbSDJdp+9IDOQEixLEtEDECPj7ra9IwfKw6QNMkAznOxihPEZHstaHLaFymRCsgtAimKHqSveCj3EcRRIeekB+LghAAO48muyFlrEIgOnphlEvgsT4gAQtgyr4mJfQGUZ9Q2fZ3BXM5P4iAATOA8TqKpjT3scJ46epHlaShuD0qxcghY8jQ8bq1mxWWUXhZpxnntxQ6EAkA5pWOMV5XFCXdvSpBvMgVDUsxOUNOxmGqeOhD0kw3DKLEAAGACqMEAOQuJSiwuAAJIIzX4IygyEBofXBZowVAA)

---

All of these options work the same way once you serialize the collections:

```
// type SerializedCollection<SerializedContact>
const serializedContactCollection = contactCollection.serialize();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Option 2 seems to be a better fit.  Is it be possible to have the `CollectionInterface` generic be the ModelInterface.  Ex: `CollectionInterface<Contact>` vs `CollectionInterface<SerializedContact>`?

Comment: I added a revision playground link in the original post

Comment: Brilliant.  Option 3 is perfect.  I was exploring the use of infer via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796871/nested-typescript-generics, but wasn't able to wrap my head around how to best implement it in this case.